# How can I control several LED strips with one remote control?

Tags: electrical, led

I want to install several LED strips that cannot be connected to each other. Each would have it's own power supply. Is there a way to control them all with a single remote control? I seen several remote controls, but they all have only one receiver. Would adding a second receiver work with the same remote controls or is there some pairing to do?

Comment: If ON/OFF control is ok, the X10 modules can be set to the same address and will turn multiple modules at the same time

Comment: No, I'm looking into changing colors as well.

Comment: You can still changes the colours with my solution as it sends the same command on the remote to all the strips.

Answer (score 2):

I purchased 4 identical systems, each with the same LED driver/controller and remote. Each LED strip had to be wired separately with it's own DRIVER/CONTROLLER.  Only one remote will operate all 4 strips.  The problem however is that the remote can get out of sync with the lights strips and then it's pure h^ll trying to get them all back in sync, only to have it happen again just a few moments later.  I to this day have no solution, unless all 4 strips are controlled by the same DRIVER/CONTROLLER, which they are not and cannot be at this stage of the construction.  Food for thought and something I will keep in my knowledge sack for future builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchase a single LED drivers and piggy back the wiring to this single driver you will be able to control them all at once. (Check Voltages First)

Alternatively you can purchase multiple LED drivers that operate using IR and install a IR Routing Kit (as seen in the image) to send the on/off command to all the strips at once.[image]